# Ember js, Can't push already normalized json api data into store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm unable to push a response into the store. According the the docs since I'm returning jsonapi spec I should be able to push it straight in without normalizing it first.

The code to push the response into the store looks like this:

```
  getCurrentUser() {
    return get(this, 'store').queryRecord('user', {self: true})
      .then((response) => {
        const user = get(this, 'store').push(response);
        set(this, 'account', user);
        return user;
      });
  }
```

This throws `You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push'`. However if I create a dummy response using the output from the server

```
 getCurrentUser() {
    return get(this, 'store').queryRecord('user', {self: true})
      .then((response) => {

        const testResponse =
        {
          "data": {
            "type": "user",
            "id": "578846b3e5438b26ebbce7d4",
            "attributes": {
              "identification": "admin",
              "display-name": "Administrator"
            },
            "relationships": {
              "servers": {
                "data": []
              },
              "jobs": {
                "data": []
              }
            }
          }
        };

        const user = get(this, 'store').push(testResponse);
        set(this, 'account', user);
        return user;
      });
  }
```

Everything works as expected. The data in `testResponse` is a straight copy and paste from postman, so should it not be the same as the data in `response` or `response.data`?

So I tried playing around with normalizing it anyway but get all sorts of errors.

```
 getCurrentUser() {
    return get(this, 'store').queryRecord('user', {self: true})
      .then((response) => {
        const [data] = response.data;
        const normalizedData = get(this, 'store').normalize('user', data);
        const user = get(this, 'store').push(normalizedData);
        set(this, 'account', user);
        return user;
      });
  }
});
```

throws `Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance TypeError`

I've tried a few different combinations of above get various errors.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I THINK response already is a store object, meaning the json object you received from the server already has been pushed to the store. Try just doing the `get(this, 'store').queryRecord('user', {self: true})` part and inspect the data tab with the ember plugin in your browser (if you dont use it yet, you should, its really helpful)

Comment: Wow looks like you're right, and thinking about it of course it would already be stored. If you want to write this in as an answer I'll happily accept.